# Is it possible to add a JRE to Installed JREs in Eclipse using relative path and Eclipse variables?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde, eclipse-jdt

Is it  possible to use Eclipse variables like `${workspace_loc}` or `${eclipse_home}` for adding a JRE to Installed JREs in the Eclipse preferences?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Can you accomplish what you need using Execution Environments? http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Execution_Environments

Comment: I am trying to define an Development environment with necessary eclipse plugins which will be used of all developers. We are deploying our jre which exists under one of our projects for the end users. I want to point to this jre as the default jre. Our Eclipse version has the 64-bit architecture (Mean a 64 bit jvm) but the jre used for end users has the 32 bits architecture. So I suppose the Execution Environments will not work anyway!

Comment: Could you specify the relative path using the -vm argument in eclipse.ini? http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: Even if it is possible to use relative paths in the eclipse.ini it will not resolve the problem. As I said we have to jres. The eclipse should use the 64 bits jre for starting with a absolute path but the code should use a 32 bits jre for using libraries or launchers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use variables for that, neither in the JRE preferences nor the execution environment specifications. And don't look at the eclipse.ini as suggested in comments, the JVM running your IDE has nothing to do with the JRE used to compile your project.

That said, there is still another easy solution (which we use in our company): Just install a second copy of the end user JVM at a known fixed location for your developers, so you can use that fixed path in the JRE preference page.

If you fear that the two JRE copies (in your project and at the fixed location) get out of sync over time, then you could use an Ant based builder to your Eclipse project, which conditionally copies the JRE from the workspace to the outside known fixed location during the build. But honestly, it does not really matter if those 2 copies get out of sync. If your code was compiled using a 32 bit JRE, it will run on another 32 bit JRE deployed at your customer anyway, as long as they are byte code compatible. And you can set that explicitly in the Java compiler settings of your Java project.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I tried two days and came to the same conclusion as you mentioned. (To have another JRE in a fixed position). Do you know if it is possible to save the prefrences for all users? I mean is there a way that all developers get the same jre configuration without configuring it. I tried to use plugin-customization and org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PREF_VM_XML but it didn't work!

Comment: use Workspace mechanic: http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/